# How to add google maps to contact us page magento2

Tags: magento2

I am new in magento. I want to add google maps into COntact Us page in magento . I am not getting how to do? Anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link of [github extension](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.ContactMap).

It will provide you this functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create this file here in your custom theme to add map on contact us page

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="google_map" template="Magento_Contact::google_map.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You need to create one template file here on this path

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Contact/templates/google_map.phtml

Content for this file is..

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:5,
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Add your MAP API Key where I've mentioned `YOUR_API_KEY` in phtml file and then run below commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Or you can [download](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-google-maps) this extension

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you for the solutions

Comment: You can approve answer if this is helpful to you! Thanks you too. :)